# Fixing Pixelation in DSM

Tags: raster, lidar, dem

I ran las dataset, then las to raster using max for DSM.  Two and a half hours later I have 3 areas showing pixilation using higher level coloring.  See enclosed image.

I found on web that seamless might work though 2,2 might be small.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try to apply Gaussian smoothing, which is used to remove noise from images, and may make the pixelation go away.

This can be done, for example, by using the tool *Gaussian filter*, which can be found in QGIS: *Processing toolbox* -> *SAGA* -> *Grid-Filter* -> *Gaussian filter*.